# How to post literally this icon: &

Tags: php, email

Hi

I'm trying to post a long text to another server for sending an email, but when the server sends the email, I'm not geting what I hope to get:

> **How it should be:**  `<a target='_blank' href='http://sosgram.ga/account/access/verify.php?id='NDA='&code=237804940a1a14644fbd1cdddc165d28> Clique aquí para activar la cuenta :)</a>`
>
> **How it is:** `<a target='_blank' href='http://sosgram.ga/account/access/verify.php?id='NDA='` - And after that, all message dissapears

---

**The files that are connected:**

SignUp File:

```php
$id = $user_index->lasdID();
$key = base64_encode($id);
$id = $key;
$code = file_get_contents("PRIVATE");
$link = "http://sosgram.ga/account/access/verify.php?id='$id'&code=$code";

$message = "
<b>Hola $fullname,
<br>
Bienvenido a SOSgram</b><br><br>
Para completar su registro, simplemente clique en el siguiente link de verificación<br><br>
<a target='_blank' href='$link'>Clique aquí para activar la cuenta :)</a>
<br><br><br>
<i>Muchas gracias,<br>
SOSgram</i>";

$subject = "Confirmar Registro en SOSgram";

$user_index->send_mail($email,$message,$subject);

$msg = "<div class='alert alert-success fade in'>
        <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
        <strong>Enhorabuena!</strong>  Su registro se ha completado correctamente.<br>
        En breve recibirá un email con un link de confirmación de su cuenta
        </div>";
```

*I posted only the code that causes my error because I checked the other code and it works good*

Functions File:

```php
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
{
    $url = 'PRIVATE/email.php';
    $myvars = 'email=' . $email . '&message=' . $message . '&subject=' . $subject;

    $ch = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
}
```

Server Email File:

```php
if ($_POST['email'] and $_POST['subject'] and $_POST['message']) {
  date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
  require 'mailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer;

  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $subject = $_POST['subject'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
  $mail->Host = "smtp.sparkpostmail.com";
  $mail->Port = 587;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = "SMTP_Injection";
  $mail->Password = "PRIATE";
  $mail->setFrom('verify@email.sosgram.ga', 'Verificación de Cuentas | SOSgram');
  $mail->addReplyTo('support@email.sosgram.ga', 'Soporte | SOSgram');
  $mail->addAddress("$email");
  $mail->Subject = "$subject";
  $mail->msgHTML("$message");

  if (!$mail->send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
  }
} else {echo "Bad Request";}
```

---

I supose that the error is in the postmethod, when the server sends the message, it interprets the link `http://sosgram.ga/account/access/verify.php?id='$id'&code=$code` as two separates post methods, **because it has an & icon**, so it trims the text and only sends the message until the &

How can I force the $_POST method to send the icon & as an icon and not as a separator in the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function.

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

and

> Returns a string in which all non-alphanumeric characters except -_. have been replaced with a percent (%) sign followed by two hex digits and spaces encoded as plus (+) signs. It is encoded the same way that the posted data from a WWW form is encoded, that is the same way as in application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type.

---

Alternatively, use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query):

> Generate URL-encoded query string

```
$base_url = "http://sosgram.ga/account/access/verify.php?";
$query = http_build_query(Array(
    id => "'$id'", # Are you sure you want to surround the id with apostrophes?
    code => $code
));
$link = $base_url . $query;
```

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot, it works perfectly with URLEncode and URLDecode

Comment: It should be decoded automatically when `$_GET` is populated.